# How do I trap an event when a scroll bar appears?

Tags: events, gwt

I have a GWT `ScrollPanel` whose `overflow-y` is set to `auto`. Is there an event that is fired when the panel's scroll bar appears or disappears?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no event fired when scroll bars are added to or removed from an element. It's not hard, however, to roll your own:

```
public class MyScrollPanel extends ScrollPanel {
  boolean horizontal = false;
  boolean vertical = false;

  public native int getScrollHeight() /*-{
    return this.@com.mypackage.MyScrollPanel::getElement()().scrollHeight;
  }-*/;

  public native int getScrollWidth() /*-{
    return this.@com.mypackage.MyScrollPanel::getElement()().scrollWidth;
  }-*/;

  private boolean hasHorizontalScrollbar() {
    return getElement().getClientWidth() < getScrollWidth();
  }

  private boolean hasVerticalScrollbar() {
    return getElement().getClientHeight() < getScrollHeight();
  }

  public void onLoad() {
    new Timer() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        boolean scrollersChanged = false;

        if (hasHorizontalScrollbar() != horizontal) {
          horizontal = !horizontal;
          scrollersChanged = true;
        }

        if (hasVerticalScrollbar() != vertical) {
          vertical = !vertical;
          scrollersChanged = true;
        }

        if (scrollersChanged) {
          // Fire event or call onResize()
        }
      }
    }.scheduleRepeating(500);
  }
}
```